# import error of matplotlib with IronPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ironpython

I am trying to use matplotlib within the Ironpython environment, using "import matplotlib.pyplot as plot".

However, I have seen this error for more than 3 hours, and could not figure out how to solve this problem.

```
cannot import _path from matplotlib
    Traceback:
      line 35, in <module>, "C:\Users\noclew\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py"
```

It seems that Ironpython cannot locate _path.pyd file, even though it can detect the location of the matplotlib location.

It will be greaaaaatly appreciated if you let me how to deal with this issue.
I am using matplotlib 1.3.1 extracted from Canopy library, and IronPython 2.7.4 32bit.

Here below is my importing code

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("mtrand") 
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino as r
import nUtil as nu

import nNetworkx as nx
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Do you have any code for us to examine?

Comment: Dear Elginat, I am trying to use IronPython within the Rhino 3D modeling Environment, and am just importing them without any code :( Do you see any problem here?

Comment: What do you mean by "matplotlib 1.3.1 **extracted from** Canopy library"?

Comment: Oh, I referenced the matplotlib directory in the Canopy IDE library folder into the current IronPython environment. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, IronPython does not support CPython .pyd files. The IronClad project attempted to do so but updating it to work with the latest IronPython and CPython would likely be an enormous undertaking.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Then, there is no good way to use MatPlotLib in IronPython at this moment?

Comment: Not as far as I know, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Sad but good to know. Need to find out some other packages to plot numpy things...