# Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '='' When importing matplotlib with IronPython

Tags: c#, python, matplotlib, ironpython

I couldn't find an answer to this strange phenomena, I really hope someone can help...

I'm using IronPython 2.7.9 to run python code from .NET 4.5 C# code (on Visual Studio 2017 Proffesional), and getting this exception:

`Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '=''`

on the line that imports from matplotlib in the python code.

here's my C# code:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\liron\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\B3D_Python\packages\IronPython.2.7.9\lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\liron\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\B3D_Python\B3D_Python\B3D_Plotting.py", scope);
dynamic test1 = scope.GetVariable("run_animation");
test1();
```

and my Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

def run_animation():
    ...do something...
```

The exception is thrown in the second python line (from matplotlib import...).

The python code runs fine when run from the Visual Studio IronPython 2.7 interpreter.

And this is the stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=unexpected token '='
Source=IronPython
StackTrace:
at IronPython.Runtime.ThrowingErrorSink.Add(SourceUnit sourceUnit, String message, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Severity severity)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Int32 start, Int32 end, String message, Int32 errorCode)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Token t, IndexSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Boolean allowIncomplete)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(TokenWithSpan t, Int32 errorCode)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(TokenWithSpan t)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.Eat(TokenKind kind)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.FinishTupleOrGenExp()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParsePrimary()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParsePower()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFactor()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpr(Int32 precedence)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpr()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseComparison()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseNotTest()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseAndTest()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseOrTest()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpression()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpressionList(Boolean& trailingComma)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParsePrintStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSmallStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSimpleStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmtTest()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFuncDef()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseDecorated()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassDef()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst(CompilerContext context)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.GetScriptCode(SourceUnit sourceCode, String moduleName, ModuleOptions options, CompilationMode mode)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.GetScriptCode(SourceUnit sourceCode, String moduleName, ModuleOptions options)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportWithNames(CodeContext context, String fullName, String[] names, Int32 level)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(String path, ScriptScope scope)
at PythonUsingApp.Class1.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\liron\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\B3D_Python\PythonUsingApp\Class1.cs:line 10
```

Please help !

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer on this question from 2014, it is not possible to use matplotlib with IronPython:

[import error of matplotlib with IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486088/import-error-of-matplotlib-with-ironpython/23491235#23491235)

Although this is a different error then the one I got.

Does anyone know if this is still the case? Is it possible to use matplotlib with IronPython?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install the libraries manually in the Lib folder attached to C# and then try. maybe this should work